# Delphi Type Casting

Tags: delphi, types, casting

I need a clarification on Delphi Type Casting
I wrote an example with two classes: TClassA and TClassB, TClassB derived from TClassA.

the code is as follows:

```
program TEST;

{$APPTYPE CONSOLE}


uses
  System.SysUtils;

type
  TClassA = class(TObject)
  public
    Member1:Integer;
    constructor Create();
    function ToString():String; override;
  end;

type
  TClassB = class(TClassA)
  public
    Member2:Integer;
    constructor Create();
    function ToString():String; override;
    function MyToString():String;
  end;

{ TClassA }

constructor TClassA.Create;
begin
  Member1 := 0;
end;

function TClassA.ToString: String;
begin
  Result := IntToStr(Member1);
end;

{ TClassB }

constructor TClassB.Create;
begin
  Member1 := 0;
  Member2 := 10;
end;

function TClassB.MyToString: String;
begin
  Result := Format('My Values is: %u AND %u',[Member1,Member2]);
end;

function TClassB.ToString: String;
begin
  Result := IntToStr(Member1) + ' - ' + IntToStr(Member2);
end;


procedure ShowInstances();
var
  a: TClassA;
  b: TClassB;
begin
  a := TClassA.Create;
  b := TClassB(a); // Casting (B and A point to the same Memory Address)
  b.Member1 := 5;
  b.Member2 := 150; // why no error? (1)

  Writeln(Format('ToString: a = %s, a = %s',[a.ToString,b.ToString])); // (2)
  Writeln(Format('Class Name: a=%s, b=%s',[a.ClassName,b.ClassName])); // (3)
  Writeln(Format('Address: a=%p, b=%p',[@a,@b])); // (4)
  Writeln(b.MyToString); // why no error? (5)

  readln;
end;

begin
  try
    ShowInstances;
  except
    on E: Exception do
      Writeln(E.ClassName, ': ', E.Message);
  end;
end.
```

The program output is:

```
ToString: a = 5, a = 5
Class Name: a=TClassA, b=TClassA
Address: a=0012FF44, b=0012FF40
My Values is: 5 AND 150
```

(1) what's the Member2 address? is this a possible "Access Violation"?
(2) ok, ToString() method point to the same address
(3) why a and b have the same ClassName?
(4) ok, a and b are two different variables
(5) if b is TClassA, why can use "MyToString" method?

Comment: These questions are a little pointless. Your cast is illegal. Don't do it.

Comment: Illegal does not mean pointless.

Comment: even if I misused the cast, I think there is a reason why the compiler allows you to do so in this way.

Comment: @AndreaBoc - by making an unsafe typecast you are saying to the compiler "Shut up. I know what I am doing". The compiler just obeys.

Comment: @Serg Ok, I understand. My comment is just because I can not find my question pointless

Comment: What can you do with the information? You'll never use this code. Once you break the rules, you can't reason in a robust manner. The compiler can behave in an unpredictable manner.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You're applying a *hard* type cast over the variable. When you do so, you're telling the compiler you know what you're doing and the compiler *trusts* you.

> (1) what's the Member2 address? is this a possible "Access Violation"?

When you assign a value to a member of the class, the class definition of the variable is used by the compiler to calculate the offset of that member in the memory space, so when you have a  class declaration like this:

```
type
  TMyClass = class(TObject)
    Member1: Integer; //4 bytes
    Member2: Integer; //4 bytes
  end;
```

the in-memory representation of this object looks like this:

```
reference (Pointer) to the object
|
|
--------> [VMT][Member1][Member 2][Monitor]
Offset     0    4        8         12
```

When you issue a statement like this:

```
MyObject.Member2 := 20;
```

The compiler just uses that information to calculate the memory address to apply that assignment to. In this case, the compiler the assignment may be translated to

```
PInteger(NativeUInt(MyObject) + 8)^ := 20;
```

So, your assignment succeeds just because the way the (default) memory manager works. An AV is originated by the operating system when you try to access a memory address that is not part of your program. In this case, your program has taken more memory from the OS than required. IMHO, when you don't get an AV, you, in fact, are unlucky, because your program memory may now be silently corrupted. Any other variable that happens to reside at that address may have changed its value (or meta-data), and it would result in undefined behavior.

> (2) ToString() method point to the same address

Since the ToString() method is a virtual one, the address of that method is stored in the VMT and the call is determined at runtime. Take a look at [What data does a TObject contain?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/679022/what-data-does-a-tobject-contain), and read the referenced book chapter: [The Delphi Object Model](http://oreilly.com/catalog/delphi/chapter/ch02.html).

> (3) why a and b have the same ClassName?

The class name is also part of the run-time metadata of the object. The fact that you're applying the wrong mold to the object doesn't change the object itself.

> (4) a and b are two different variables

Of course, you declared it, look at your code:

```
var
  a: TClassA;
  b: TClassB;
```

Well, two different variables. In Delphi, the object variables are references, so, after some lines of code both reference the same address, but that's a different thing.

> (5) if b is TClassA, why can use "MyToString" method?

Because you're telling the compiler that's OK, and as said, the compiler trusts you. It is hacky, but Delphi is also a low level language and you're allowed to do a lot of crazy things, if you want, but:

## Play safe

If you want (and you surely want most of the time) to be on the safe side, don't apply a hard cast like that in your code. Use the [**as** operator](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/XE3/en/Class_References#The_as_Operator):

> The **as** operator performs checked typecasts. The expression
>
> *object* **as** *class*
>
> returns a reference to the same object as object, but with the type given by class. At runtime, object must be an instance of the class denoted by class or one of its descendants, or be nil; otherwise an exception is raised. If the declared type of object is unrelated to class - that is, if the types are distinct and one is not an ancestor of the other - a compilation error results.

So, with the as operator, you're safe, both at compile-time and at run-time.

Change your code to:

```
procedure ShowInstance(A: TClassA);
var
  b: TClassB;
begin
  b := A as TClassB; //runtime exception, the rest of the compiled code 
                     //won't be executed if a is not TClassB
  b.Member1 := 5;
  b.Member2 := 150; 

  Writeln(Format('ToString: a = %s, a = %s',[a.ToString,b.ToString])); 
  Writeln(Format('Class Name: a=%s, b=%s',[a.ClassName,b.ClassName])); 
  Writeln(Format('Address: a=%p, b=%p',[@a,@b])); 
  Writeln(b.MyToString); 

  readln;
end;

procedure ShowInstances();
begin
  ShowInstance(TClassB.Create); //success
  ShowInstance(TClassA.Create); //runtime failure, no memory corrupted.
end;
```

Comment: FWIW, the memory layout is a little different, these days: Member1 is at offset 8 and at offset 4 there is a Monitor field.

Comment: @Rudy, the Monitor field is at the end of the object, not at the beginning, as shown in the answer.

Comment: Yes, you are right. It still beats me why they do it that way, but hey, it is their problem.

Comment: "when you DON'T get an AV, you in fact are unlucky" - Nicely said! Indeed AV is your friend! Don't hate them. Love them (and fix them).

Answer (score 4):

1. `Member2` has an address that was not allocated by a memory manager. The possible result of writing to `Member2` is heap corruption with subsequent access violations in a totally different part of a program. This is a very nasty bug and compiler can't help you here. You must know what are you doing when making unsafe type casting.
2. That is because `ToString` method is virtual, so its address is determined by the actual type of the class instance being created. If you replace virtual method by static (in your case by replacing `override` directive by `reintroduce`) the result will be different.
3. Because `ClassName` method is kinda virtual too (not really a member of VMT, but that is insignificant implementation detail).
4. Yes, `a` and `b` are two references to the same instance.
5. Because `ToMyString` method is static. The actual type of the instance does not matter for static methods.

Comment: Actually there is no heap corruption because in this case he is writing into the TMonitor field which is the last field in an instance. Try calling TMonitor.Enter(b) which results in an AV (Read of address 000000A6) for proof.

Comment: @StefanGlienke - That is true for Delphi 2009+. AFAIK `Monitor` field was introduced in Delphi 2009.

Comment: D2009+ or not, that's heap corruption. You expect the address of a TMonitor to exist at a location on the heap, but it's overwritten.

Comment: @SertacAkyuz - no, `Monitor` is now the last pointer-size field of any object. So in this particular case heap is not corrupted - `Monitor` field is corrupted instead.

Comment: @Serg - Isn't this monitor field on the heap?

Comment: @SertacAkyuz - It is a part of the object instance. It is allocated with object instance.

Comment: @Serg - My point was, since object instance memory is allocated from the heap, the monitor field also lives in the heap. But nevermind, I failed to make my point..

Comment: @SertacAkyuz - I got you. It is heap corruption, but it affects only this particular instance. :)

Answer (score 3):

> (1) what's the Member2 address? is this a possible "Access Violation"?

Yes. AV is possible. In your case you have luck :)

> ok, ToString() method point to the same address

Yes as VTable is concerned at creation time.

> (3) why a and b have the same ClassName?

same answer as in (2).

> (4) ok, a and b are two different variables

Not really. you printed address from stack :)

> (5) if b is TClassA, why can use "MyToString" method?

b is TClassB but **by mistake** points to TClassA instance.

You should use **as** operator for such casts. In this case it would fail.

Comment: Actually, I wouldn't call it luck. He is overwriting something but doesn't notice it. I rather get a clear AV.